# How to add function on table fields - Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have this code in a Backbone application that I need to debug. (rough idea)

```
window.TableView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {...
..
..
...
        });

    },
    selectRow: function() {
...
...
..

    },
    render: function() { // this renders my models fields in a table

        var editableColumns = [
            //{ name: "display", type: "combobox", combobox: comboboxOptions, validate: validateText },
            { name: "display" },
            { name: "submitDate", type: "datepicker", datepicker: datepickerOptions },
            { name: "displayDate", type: "datepicker", datepicker: datepickerOptions },
            { name: "name"},
...
...
```

Now my problem is, how can I add a function to this field: `{ name: "display" }`
like onclick, or after focus function, etc.? For example can I have,

`{ name: "display", onclick: setMyText(); }` or something like this? Also is this part of backbone.js or one of its components? Where can I read more about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Backbone` you have `events` hash for a `View` where you can specify the `events` for respective `View`. Events are specified in following format:

```
{"event selector": "callback"}
```

So in your case for all the `editableColumns` you also need a `selector` for each one or may you can specify by using the `name` property. Try specifying the `events` hash like this :

```
events: {
    'click .columnSelector[name="display"]' : "setMyText"
}
```

where `.columnSelector` is the `class` applied to `element` that is to be edited.

For more details on `events` check [this](http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents).